# Change https header 302 to 200 in PHP

Tags: http-status-codes, http-status-code-302

E-Commerce website has product page and category page. Now when user visiting any product and if not available then user will redirect to category page with 302 header status code of product page, I want to change that from 302 to 200, How can I make that possible ?

In short, How can I change http header from 302 to 200 ok in PHP

Answer (score 2):

If you add the following option at the top of a PHP file before any output then it will change the status to 200.

```
header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
```

Comment: ...although I am not sure why in this case you would want to do that?

Comment: @ actually, this is client requirement to set for SEO purpose.

Comment: I am using MVC structure, There is a function which handle this logic to redirect, I tried to put before redirection code, but fails.header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");header("Location: www.xyz.com");

Comment: It has to go in the file that the browser is redirected to.